# SQL INSERT stored procedure not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create Proc CrearNuevoAnuncio
    @Titulo varchar(250),
    @Precio int,
    @Descripcion varchar(250),
    @IDCategoria int,
    @IDImagen int,  
    @Login varchar(200)

AS

INSERT INTO Anuncio VALUES(
    @Titulo,
    @Precio,
    @Descripcion,
    @IDCategoria,
    @IDImagen,  
    @Login
    )
```

The error is because the table anuncio has 1 more attribute: "idAnuncio". It's the primary key, and it's the indentity (autoincrement).

So, how can I handle this is the missing thing is an Identity. I don't want to pass that parameter from my front-end.

Comment: 3rd time with the bad tag. tsk tsk.  It's really not that hard to type 'sql-server'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the explicit list of columns in your insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO 
   Anuncio(Titulo, Precio, Descripcion, IDCategoria, IDImagen, Login)
VALUES
   (@Titulo, @Precio, @Descripcion, @IDCategoria, @IDImagen,  @Login)
```

Otherwise, SQL Server will try to insert values for ALL columns which fails here. It cannot insert a value into an IDENTITY column - that column will be set automatically by SQL Server upon inserting a new row, and is guaranteed to be unique.

Is the ID field of type "INT IDENTITY" ? In that case, you could access the value of the newly inserted ID like this:

```
 DECLARE @NewID INT
 SET @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

and possibly return it from the stored proc:

```
 RETURN @NewID
```

Marc

Comment: Not really answered my question. I want to insert a new record, but IdAnuncio is an IDENTITY which autoincrements whenever there is a new record. How can I create a stored procedure taking this into account?

Comment: Ok, I modified my code using your example above, and the procedure executed correctly (it got created), so I take it that my PrimaryKey(identity-type) will autoincrement regardless if it's not mentioned even once in my stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, an "IDENTITY" field will be automatically handled by the database - that's the whole point of having an IDENTITY

Comment: All I needed to know. :3 Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify which value goes to which field.

```
INSERT INTO Anuncio (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (@Titulo, ...)
```